# Difference between System.today() and System.today().day() in apex?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have a schedule apex job that runs everyday in the morning at 2 AM, where I am trying to gather opportunities where custom date `Reoffer_Date__c` as today.

```
List opportunitiesList = [
        SELECT Id, Name, Employee_Contact__c, RecordTypeId, Employee_Contact__r.Gross_Income__c
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Reoffer_Date__c = System.TODAY()
];
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is exactly, but you can easily solve this with using the Date Literals in SOQL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm Just use `SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Reoffer_Date__c = TODAY`

Comment: Please form an actual question so the community can try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

As already proposed in the comments section, please tak a look at date literals like `TODAY`: 
[Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

In terms of `day()`, it returns the day-of-month component of a Date ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)). So if you want to have a full date, it's not the way to go.

As for the `today`, it returns current date (honoring user's time zone) indeed. It would be best for you to just review existing methods for [System Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm).